# Writing a parametrization of the cissoid by using $\theta$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

The cissoid of Diocles is the curve whose equation in terms of polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ is
$$r = \sin\theta \tan\theta, −\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta <\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Write down a parametrization of the cissoid using $\theta$ as a parameter and show that

$$\gamma(t)=\left(t^2, \frac{t^3}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)$$ for $-1\lt t\lt 1$

is a parametrization of it.

---

I researched what is the cissoid of Diocles. And I reached the following graph result;

[image]

---

I found the question a differential geometry textbook while I am studying by myself . 
Please help me solving the question. Thank you:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost have the answer already. Recall the definition of polar coordinates:
$$x=r\cos\theta,\qquad y=r\sin\theta.$$
Now you have an expression for $r$ in terms of $\theta$. Replacing it in these formulas we get
\begin{align}
&x=\sin\theta\tan\theta\cdot\cos\theta=\sin^2\theta,\\
&y=\sin\theta\tan\theta\cdot\sin\theta=\frac{\sin^3\theta}{\cos\theta}.
\end{align}
This is a parameterization of $x$ and $y$ by $\theta$. Now if instead of $\theta$ we use $t=\sin\theta$ as a new parameter, these formulas will transform into
$$x=t^2,\qquad y=\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

Comment: +1 Wow! knowing the definition of polar coordinates $x$ and $y$ is enough. Everything is clear:) Thank you very much:)

Comment: @B11b You are very welcome.